# How to change the Page title from Home to Search at the master page level?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

One of the Projects I am working on, i have a requirement to change the text "Home" that appears as a page title on the landing page of a sharepoint team site. I am able to hide Home from the master page but not sure how to replace that with a different text. 
Is this doable using CSS since I already have master page in place.

[image]

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: That is usually the name/title of the site (or a page), so the easiest way would be to change the site or page name/title from Home to Search. If that doesn't work, you could probably use some javascript to get that span and change it's innerText.

Comment: Hi Damjan, can you help me with the code though? the span ID is: DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to change it through the javascript. Make sure to include the jquery to the page, and this code should do it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").html("Search");
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Damjan can you please review this question as well:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243092/how-to-split-top-navigation-items-into-two-rows   thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Damjan, This works but it also change the Settings text on list or library settings page to Search and I do not want that, is there a way to exclude the list or library pages from this?