# How to increase the font-size of Home link in quick launch?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am using below code to change the font-size of the Home Link that appears in the Quick Launch but its not working. Can someone please help me with the correct code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > .ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Home')").css('font-size', '2.77em');

</script>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding your code to document ready event. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > .ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Home')").css('font-size', '2.77em');
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Damjan, yes it works. Thanks. I actually have to apply the text color #009933 and I tried below but does not work, any help?

Comment: $(".ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > .ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Home')").css('font-size', '2.77em','color','#009933');

Comment: just split it in two calls:
$(".ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > .ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Home')").css('color','#009933');
$(".ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > .ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Home')").css('font-size', '2.77em');

Comment: or better chain the calls: $(".ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-root > li > .ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Home')").css('color','#009933').css('font-size', '2.77em');

Comment: Thanks man, can you check this question and help me with answer as well:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243082/how-to-change-the-page-title-from-home-to-search-at-the-master-page-level