# How to split top navigation items into two rows?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

One of the Projects I am working on, I have a requirement to split 9 top sharepoint navigation links into two rows. I have a master page in action. I would need to display 5 of the navigation links in the first row and then 4 in the second row. Is this possible, can someone help me with the CSs , JS/JQ code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with some javascript - add the `<br/>` tag after the 5th menu item. Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id ^=zz][id $=_RootAspMenu] li li").children(":eq(4)").parent().after("<br/>")
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Damjan, could you explain what zz and _RootAspMenu indicate in terms of id?

Comment: The id of the ul tag that holds the menu is not fixed, but it always starts with zz and ends with _RootAspMenu (it is usually zz1_RootAspMenu or zz12_RootAspMenu), so with this selector we solve that problem (we find the tag whose id starts with zz and ends with _RootAspMenu).